# GOPATH entry is relative must be Absolut path ,How can solve it

Tags: go, installation, environment-variables, gopath

[image]

go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "%Jittu%\go".
For more details see: 'go help gopath

Comment: can you share your project location and go path/path variables?

Comment: I think you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good question

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: As for solving it: You have two choices: 1) Do what the error says, and make it an absolute path. 2) Preferred: Don't use GOPATH. It's practically obsolete by now. Use Go modules instead.

Comment: @JonathanHall What do you exactly mean to do to use Go modules. A build error mentioning GO111MODULES shows up?

Answer (score 3):

Go doesn't expand Windows (or any other) environmental variables in `GOPATH`. You need to provide absolute path, e.g.  `setx GOPATH "C:\Users\Jittu\go"`.

If you want to use other variable to set `GOPATH` it must be expanded at the time of setting `GOPATH` so that `GOPATH` is always seen by Go only as absolute path.